# nginx and meteorjs - how to rewrite the URL to include port?

Tags: meteor, nginx

I confused on how to rewrite the URL for meteorjs requests that has a http address of `http://IP/<LettersHere>meteor_js_resource=true` to `http://IP:3000/<LettersHere>meteor_js_resource=true`.

If I access my site's URL:3000, then I can get all the static files from the meteor application.

[image]

However, if I tried this nginx configuration file to route `URL:3000` to `URL/someURL` so when people access my site, they don't need the 3000 port number, but instead `/someURL`:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;

    server_name domain.com;

    location /youtube-channel-search 
    {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      rewrite http://domain.com http://domain.com:3000 permanent;
    }
}
```

Then I get an error where the js file cannot be found:

[image]

This is correct, since `http://IP/URL` is not `http://IP:3000/URL`.

How should I rewrite the incoming requests to add an extra port :3000? I thought the proxy_pass automatically takes care of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

You will need to change ROOT_URL environmental parameter of the meteorJS application to `localhost:3000/youtube-channel-search`.

Using the same nginx.conf would work.

This is because some of the sockjs and static files are mapped to the `localhost:3000`, without the trailing `/youtube-channel-search`.